# Regex - everything between last period and last underscore

Tags: regex

I'm trying to formulate a regex that captures everything after last period, up until (not including) underscore number 3 AFTER the period.

For example:

```
ABC_Simple_DEF.dbo.GDE_1_1_Contact_test
```

should return `GDE_1_1`.

I've tried using `[^.]+$` which includes everything after the last period. 
The expression `_[^_]+$` includes last underscore and everything after, which is close, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Kinda stuck here and would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[^._]+(?:_[^._]+){2}(?=_[^.]*$)
```

Or, capturing approach (you will need to grab Group 1 value from the result):

```
([^._]+(?:_[^._]){2})_[^.]*$
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/NqqIn7/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/NqqIn7/2).

**Details**

- `[^._]+` - 1+ chars other than `.` and  `_`
- `(?:_[^._]+){2}` -  two repetitions of

  - `_`  - an underscore
  - `[^._]+` - 1+ chars other than `.` and  `_`
- `(?=_[^.]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `_` and 0+ chars other than `.` up to the end of string immediately to the right of the current position.

Comment: Perfect, just what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a negative lookbehind is supported, one option could be to assert what is on the left is a dot and use a negative lookahead to assert no more dots after the matched one:

```
(?<=\.)(?!.*\.)(?:[^_]+_){2}[^_]+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\.)` Negative behind, assert what is directly on the left is not a dot
- `(?!.*\.)` Negative lookahead, assert not more dots following
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^_]+_` match 1+ times not an underscore, then an `_`
- `){2}` Close non capturing group and repeat 2 times
- `[^_]+` Match 1+ times not an `_`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bIpXzv/1)

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation over Wiktor's answer, that requires a last period and captures everything until the third underscore, or until the end if there are less than three (non-capturing groups dropped for clarity, test [here](https://regex101.com/r/YrqOXi/1)) :

```
\.([^._]*(_[^._]*){0,2})[^.]*$
```

The target capture group is 1. To better visualize, suppose your input contains only underscores, periods, and the character `c`, then it becomes :

```
\.(c*(_c*){0,2})c*$
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight "dumb" regex is:

```
([^.]*\.)*([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*).*
```

and you need group `\1`

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/gpUvXP/1).